# Problem initiating ReplicaSet node using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, pymongo

I'm trying to write a python script which goal is to initiate a MongoDB replicaset node in my development environment (note: I have just one single node) without having to use mongo shell. So the script is intended to be manually run once.

I run MongoDB using docker and this is part of my docker-compose file:

```
mongodb:
    image: "mongo:5.0-focal"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db    
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--replSet",
        "rs0" 
      ]
```

I run the following python code in another docker container belonging to the same network so that it has visibility on the host name *mongodb*. My pymongo version is 4.0.1

```
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    client = MongoClient('mongodb',27017,serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000)
    config = { '_id': 'rs0', 'members': [{'_id': 0, 'host': 'mongodb:27017'}]}
    print("REPLICA SET config:")
    print(config)
    out = client.admin.command("replSetInitiate", config)
    print(out)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error!")
    print(e)
    pass
```

running the script I've got this error:

```
No servers match selector "Primary()", Timeout: 5.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61c0dffc7f72958bdd10e65f, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb', 27017) server_type: RSGhost, rtt: 0.004416499999933876>]>
```

Ok, no server matches Primary selector, but how can I have a Primary if I don't initiate a replicaSet first?  Not an expert in pymongo and MongoDB but am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar issue and came across https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-3027. Passing 'directConnection=True' as a parameter to MongoClient seemed to help. Although, am not sure about how this works.

Comment: And yes! That's it. Thanks a lot @Netra.
I've found this description in the [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html):
directConnection (optional): if True, forces this client to
connect directly to the specified MongoDB host as a standalone. If false, the client connects to the entire replica set of which the given MongoDB host(s) is a part. If this is True and a mongodb+srv:// URI or a URI containing multiple seeds is provided, an exception will be raised.
Adding the parameter fixed the issue.